# Summing together user input data

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add together user input numbers but its returning some super large number. If someone could help that would be great, thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int attemptno = 1;
    int str[a]; //array
    int x;

    for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
        cout << "Person " << attemptno++ << ", how many pancakes did you have for breakfast? " << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }

    int sum;
    sum = 0;
    sum = sum + str[a];
    cout << "Total number of pancakes eaten is: " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should not compile.

Comment: What is the value of `a`? How big will the array be? And do you remember what the max index of an array of size `a` is? And lastly, you are aware of that C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?

Comment: a = 10, so i just want 10 inputs.

Comment: I also suggest you do attempt of [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: No, `a` is *not* equal to `10`? Where in the code do you say that?

Comment: could i write sum = str[0] + str[1] + etc..

Comment: i want it to be 10, shall i change it to int str[10]; then?

Comment: That's a good start. And you should probably assign to `str[i]` somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating sum from array values: 
`sum = sum + str[a];`, but while getting input values you don't populate your array. Actually in this case, you don't need an array to calculate sum. You can calculate sum while getting input values, like this:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int attemptno = 1;
    int x;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
        cout << "Person " << attemptno++ << ", how many pancakes did you have for breakfast? " << endl;
        cin >> x;
        sum = sum + x;
    }

    cout << "Total number of pancakes eaten is: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never setting the elements of `str`, so `str' is uninitialized.

```
sum = sum + str[a];
```

Is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: true, got tricked by the `int a = 0` in the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `str[]` are never initialised, and `a` too, and the behaviour on reading their contents prior to initialisation is *undefined*. You must have an *extremely* flacid compiler for this to have produced a program.

Why not use

```
std::vector<int> str(a);
```

instead, having set `a` to something reasonable?

Then you can use the fancy

```
#include <numeric>
sum = std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), 0);
```

to evaluate the total.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to do this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //      int a;    // << deleted
  int attemptno = 1;
  int str[10];     // << changed array of 10 elements
  int x;

  for (int a = 0; a<10; a++) {
    cout << "Person " << attemptno++ << ", how many pancakes did you have for breakfast? " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    str[a] = x;    // << added
  }

  int sum = 0;

  for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)  // << added for loop
  {
    sum = sum + str[a];
  }

  cout << "Total number of pancakes eaten is: " << sum << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

See `<< added` comments for modifications I did to your original program.
This solution is still naive and can be done in a more elegant fashion in C++.

Comment: what things could be done to make it 'more elegant'?

Comment: @lg299 using C++ Features as suggestes in Bathsheba's answer.